# Angular Nested Directives

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I'm trying to have a Child Directive with Isolated scope execute a function. I can't seem to have a directive with an Isolated Scope execute a function of its parent scope. It just doesn't work.

```
UsageA:
<div data-outer data-controller="control"><div data-inner></div></div>

Usage B:
<div data-inner data-controller="controlTwo"></div>


app.controller('control', ['$scope', function($scope){
$scope.onOuterChange = function () {
    alert("Outer Change");
}
}]);

app.controller('controlTwo', ['$scope', function($scope){
$scope.onInnerChange = function () {
    alert("Inner Change");
}
}]);

app.directive('outer', function($compile){
// Runs during compile
return {
    scope: {
        "onOuterChange": "&",
    },
    controller: function ($scope, $element) {
    },
    link: function ($scope, iElm, iAttrs, controller) {
        $scope.onInnerChange = function () {
            alert("Inner Changed");
        }
    }
}
});
app.directive('inner', function($compile){
// Runs during compile
return {
    scope: {
        "onInnerChange": "&",
    },
    controller: function ($scope, $element) {
    },
    link: function ($scope, iElm, iAttrs, controller) {
        $scope.onInnerChange();
    }
}
});
```

Answer (score 0):

In an isolated scope you have to specify the method in the html as well.

```
<div data-outer on-outer-change="onOuterChange()"><div data-inner></div></div>
```

Comment: what `data-controller="control"`in directive??

Answer (score 0):

You were missing to add `on-outer-change` to outer directive that will have function name which you want to pass to isolated scope directive like `on-outer-change="onOuterChange()"`. Then to inner directive you should pass that method to `onInnerChange` scope variable of `inner` directive isolated scope.

**Markup**

```
<div data-outer on-outer-change="onOuterChange()">
    <div data-inner on-inner-change="onOuterChange()"></div>
</div>
```

**Code**

```
app.directive('outer', function($compile) {
  // Runs during compile
  return {
    scope: {
      "onOuterChange": "&",
    },
    restrict: 'A',
    controller: function($scope, $element) {},
    link: function($scope, iElm, iAttrs, controller) {
      $scope.onInnerChange = function() {
        scope.onOuterChange();
      }
    }
  }
});
app.directive('inner', function($compile) {
  // Runs during compile
  return {
    scope: {
      "onInnerChange": "&",
    },
    controller: function($scope, $element) {},
    link: function($scope, iElm, iAttrs, controller) {
      $scope.onInnerChange();
    }
  }
});
```

[**Demo here**](http://plnkr.co/edit/ZSj4yojSRdzXyR8Sl23g?p=preview)

Comment: The only issue is that the outer directive will always be used with the inner directive. I would like the inner directive to assume the function is always there..?

Comment: then you should use `require: '^outer'` in inner controller.this will make sure inner always contain outer as parent

Comment: But the inner controller doesn't depend on the outer.. Only the outer controller depends on the inner.

Comment: @MatBee how can outer controller is depend on inner?

Comment: @MatBee for ensuring the `outer` directive should be parent can be done by only using `require: '^outer' ` only